# show error if Xml element is less than 15 words

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest, xml-namespaces

Show the error message if the Element tag  value is less than 15 words?

This is my xml file

```xml
<books>
  <book id="bk110">
    <author>O'Brien, Tim</author>
    <title>Microsoft .NET: The Programming Bible</title>
    <genre>Computer</genre>
    <price>36.95</price>
    <publish_date>2000-12-09</publish_date>
    <description>Microsoft's .NET initiative is explored in detail in this deep programmer's reference.</description>
  </book>
  <book id="bk111">
    <author>O'Brien, Tim</author>
    <title>MSXML3: A Comprehensive Guide</title>
    <genre>Computer</genre>
    <price>36.95</price>
    <publish_date>2000-12-01</publish_date>
    <description>The Microsoft MSXML3 parser is covered in detail, with attention to XML DOM interfaces, XSLT processing, SAX and more.</description>
  </book>
</books>
```

I am stucked. I am not getting logic

Comment: Which element of the various elements in that XML sample? Which are the tools you want to use or can use? In XSLT/XPath 2.0 you can use e.g. `count(tokenize(description, '\s+')) lt 15` as a rough measure.

Comment: The problem with your request is defining what is a "word" for the purposes of the count. For example, how many words is "merry-go-round"?